# RowSelection in dynamically created p:datatable return 0th row always

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a task of making dynamic table from any query, I have so far done all the tasks but stuck at the point of selecting the row, when any row is selected, the 0th row no is shown and values in that row are returned.

the managed bean is

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;

@ManagedBean(name="liveRangeService", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped

public class LiveRangeService implements Serializable {

    private List< Map<String, String> > tableData;
    private Map<String, String> selectedData;
    private List< Map<String, String> > filteredData;
    private int Sr;
    private List<String> tableHeaderNames;
    private String tableColWidths;
    private List< Map<String, String> > selectedRow;
    private String RowSelected;

    public String getRowSelected() {
        return RowSelected;
    }

    public void setRowSelected(String RowSelected) {
        this.RowSelected = RowSelected;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSelectedData() {
        return selectedData;
    }

    public void setSelectedData(Map<String, String> selectedData) {
        this.selectedData = selectedData;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getTableData() {
        return tableData;
    }
    public List<String> getTableHeaderNames() {
        return tableHeaderNames;
    }

    public LiveRangeService() {
    }

    public void LiveRangeServicesss(String Qry) {
        System.out.println("Qry: " + Qry);
        tableData = new ArrayList< Map<String, String> >();
        tableHeaderNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        tableHeaderNames.add("ID");
        tableHeaderNames.add("Title");
        tableHeaderNames.add("Opn_Amt");
        tableHeaderNames.add("Smr_Amt");

        {
            Map<String, String> playlist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            playlist.put("ID", "1010001");
            playlist.put("Title", "Share Capital - Mr. 1");
            playlist.put("Opn_Amt", "0");
            playlist.put("Smr_Amt", "0");
            tableData.add(playlist);
        }

        {
            Map<String, String> playlist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            playlist.put("ID", "1010002");
            playlist.put("Title", "Share Capital - Mr. 2");
            playlist.put("Opn_Amt", "0");
            playlist.put("Smr_Amt", "0");
            tableData.add(playlist);
        }

        {
            Map<String, String> playlist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            playlist.put("ID", "1010003");
            playlist.put("Title", "Share Capital - Mrs. 3");
            playlist.put("Opn_Amt", "0");
            playlist.put("Smr_Amt", "0");
            tableData.add(playlist);
        }

        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:dlgTBL");
        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('dlg').show();");
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getSelectedRow() {
        try {System.out.println("Selected Row! " + selectedRow.size());} catch (Exception e) {}

        return selectedRow;
    }

    public void setSelectedRow(List<Map<String, String>> selectedRow) {
//        System.out.println( "selected size: " + selectedRow.size() );
        this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    }

    public String getTableColWidths() {
        return tableColWidths;
    }

    public void setTableColWidths(String tableColWidths) {
        this.tableColWidths = tableColWidths;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getFilteredData() {
        return filteredData;
    }

    public void setFilteredData(List<Map<String, String>> filteredData) {
        this.filteredData = filteredData;
    }

    public void onRowSelect() {
        System.out.println("Select Table Values: " + this.Sr + ", " + this.RowSelected);
    }

    public int getSr() {
        return Sr;
    }

    public void setSr(int Sr) {
        this.Sr = Sr;
    }
}
```

and the html portion is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:messages>
                <p:autoUpdate />
            </p:messages>
            <p:commandButton value="Update Grid" action="#{liveRangeService.LiveRangeServicesss('Select ID, Title, Opn_Amt, Smr_Amt From Coa32 Order By Title')}" id="cmdUpdate" />

            <p:dialog id="dlgTBL" modal="true" showEffect="bounce" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
                <p:dataTable var="result" id="tbl" widgetVar="dtlTBL"
                                    value="#{liveRangeService.tableData}" 
                                    paginator="false"
                                    scrollable="true"  rowIndexVar="rowIndex"  scrollHeight="500" 
                                    scrollRows="50" liveScroll="true"
                                    filterDelay="1100"
                                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{liveRangeService.rowSelected}"
                                    rowKey="#{liveRangeService.sr}"
                    >
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{liveRangeService.onRowSelect}"  />
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel layout="inline" styleClass="tabSpacer">
                            <h:outputText value="Global Filter:" />
                            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('dtlTBL').filter()" style="width:150px;margin-left:10px;"/>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column width="10">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sr." />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:columns value="#{liveRangeService.tableHeaderNames}"
                               var="mycolHeader" 
                               width="#{colIndex==0?'10%':colIndex==1?'70%':colIndex==2?'10%':colIndex==3?'10%':'0'}" 
                               columnIndexVar="colIndex" 
                               sortBy="#{result[mycolHeader]}"
                               filterBy="#{result[mycolHeader]}"
                               filterMatchMode="contains"                        
                               >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{mycolHeader}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{result[mycolHeader]}" />
                        <br />
                    </p:columns>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I have confused understanding about setting row key and also unable to set Sr. fixed column in the table, the code  always returns 0 in fixed column.  Pls suggest some solution.

Comment: Please See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info about a [mcve] and specifically the db things

Comment: The rowKey must be unique per row. It is needed to identify a row for selection. Your current rowKey is equal for all rows und returns `null` as per your current source code.

Comment: @kukeltje, thanx for your comments, i will take care in the future.  I have edited the code and hv made it reproduceable without having any db connection. pls check and advise.

Comment: I see lots of sql packages, a custom ` dbConnectionSQLServer` class (lowercase is btw uncommon) and the xhtml is not complete and still verbose (or does it work without the livescroll etc?) and please copy-paste the code above (and just that) in a new empty jsf/primefaces project. Does it run? So no it is not reproduceable yet... And @Seleron is right (but I personally do not inspect code in posts anymore when it is not a [mcve]. To many time I was put on the wrong foot (bad copy/pastes) or it took too much time. Cheers

Comment: And did you try with static columns? Most likely it would not work then either...

Comment: i m extremely sorry for my carelessness, i now have uploaded a complete working example, easily reproduceable in net beans 8.2. Sorry again, i have checked with a static column example from github but that example has complete backing beans set which i want to avoid.

Comment: i have a workout for the problem which gave me the solution for the time being although is not the ideal one, i have uploaded current code. I made row no a command button also i updated filteredlist as i filled tabledata.

Comment: questions are for questions, not temporaty solutions and titles should not contain that sort of info. I reverted the edits but please post your 'temporary solution' as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i am still unable to do it through row selection, but i did a work around by making Sr No as a button and calling on row select thru the button, i have uploaded complete code above.

```
<p:column width="50">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sr." />
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton style="width: 49px" action="#{liveRangeService.onRowSelect(rowindex)}"/>
                    </p:column>
```

Furthermore, as the filters and sorting was affecting serial no, hence giving wrong row no, i set filtereddata after filling tableData;

```
filteredData=tableData;
```

i would love if some body could suggest the right way of doing all thru row selection instead of command button.